# go back to first instruction when there is an error

Tags: c++

I am creating a simple console application that obtain user input which is an integer.

I want the condition so that it should only be an integer and it should be not more than 3 and not less than 0.

The code i came up so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int uinval;

    while (true) {
        string tempoval;
        cout << "Please enter a value between 0-3:\n>";
        cin >> tempoval;

        stringstream ss(tempoval);
        if (ss >> uinval)
        {
            break;
            cout << "Entered an invalid value";
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (uinval < 0 || uinval > 3)
                break;
            cout << "Value must be between 0-3";
        }

        cout << "You have entered:" << uinval;

        return 0;
    }
```

This works when I input a non-integer value like a,b,c,d. But it does not work when i input -1 or 4 as value.

I am not sure, maybe I confused myself with the while loops.

Comment: Make sure you indent you code properly. If your '}' always lines up with the while or if it belongs to, the while loops become a lot less confusing.

Comment: also, use `{}` for one-line if statements too. it improves readability and maintainability

Comment: @stefan it is also the subject of holy wars ;-)

Comment: @wolfgang I know, but I'm obviously right ;-)

Comment: @wolfgang: +1, I just ran the code through astyle and the brackets don't even match (as you can see in the edited question). Ravensmith450 please fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
while(true){
   if(uinval < 0 || uinval > 3)
     break;
     cout <<"Value must be between 0-3";
}
```

You check the condition on `uinval` repeatedly, without giving user a chance to enter a new value.

To fix the problem, remove the second loop, and replace

```
if(ss >> uinval) {
    break;
}
```

inside the first loop with

```
if(ss >> uinval && uinval >= 0 && uinval < 4) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your if statement holding the opposite of what you want it to.

Right now if the value is under 0 or over 3, it'll break and continue. You want it to continue if it's over 0 and under 3.

```
if(uinval > 0 && uinval < 3)
```